# Equivalent to UNIQUE IDENTIFIER in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, uuid, sqldatatypes

I was tryiong to switch from MSSQL to PostgreSQL and hence trying to convert queries to PostgreSQL equivalent. However running PostgreSQL query is giving an error:

> ERROR:  type "uniqueidentifier" does not exist LINE 3:   ID
>   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT UUID_GENERATE_V4()::VARCHAR NO...
>                ^ SQL state: 42704 Character: 38

**MSSQL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ISS_AUDIT]
(
  [ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() NOT NULL,
  [GRAPH_ID] [varchar](196)
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

**PostgreSQL**

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE public.ISS_AUDIT
(
  ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT UUID_GENERATE_V4()::VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  GRAPH_ID VARCHAR(196),
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Am I missing something on **UNIQUEIDENTIFIER**  ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct script:

```
CREATE TABLE public.ISS_AUDIT
(
  ID uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT UUID_GENERATE_V4(),
  GRAPH_ID VARCHAR(196)
);
```

See this [link](https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/179-Universal-Unique-Identifiers-PostgreSQL-SQL-Server-Compare.html). Extract:

> SQL Server calls the type UniqueIdentifier and PostgreSQL calls the
>   type uuid. Both types occupy 16-bytes of storage. For compatibility
>   reasons with other software or databases, many use some stanardized
>   text representation of them particularly for transport rather than
>   using the native type.

Answer (score 3):

We need **UUID** which can be used as below:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE public.ISS_AUDIT(
  ID UUID DEFAULT UUID_GENERATE_V4()::UUID NOT NULL,
  GRAPH_ID VARCHAR(196),
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```